# When EXECUTE AS user = 'dbo', permissions are being denied to view/query other DB objects

Tags: sql-server, security

I have sysadmin privileges on a SQL Server (2014). When I query the table `sys.databases` from one of my user database (test_db) I get the full list of databases (13 of them inclusive of system databases) that are actually on the server.

But when I execute as 'dbo', some kind of permission deny seems to be applied and the full list of databases don't appear. Neither am I able to see the list of databases nor I am not able to query objects within them as well. For example: I am not able to query `msdb.dbo.sysjobs`.

Here is what I am running on my user database called "test_db":

```
EXECUTE AS user = 'dbo'
```

Then I do the following query:

```
select * from sys.databases
```

I see only 3 databases (out of 13 databases) as shown below (master, tempdb, test_db):

[image: 3_Dbs]

I checked the login and principal identifications after the "execute as" and below you can see what those are:

[image: usernames]

After `revert`, it executes as myself and I am able to see the full list of DBs back again.

As user 'dbo' which is the database principal for server principal 'sa' it is supposed to have full `db_owner` access across all databases on the server, but unfortunately it is not so, in this case.

One additional information here is, "test_db" gets restored from a prod server backup every 2 weeks.

Can you help me to figure out why this is happening, please?

*Edit: sorry i meant server principal 'sa' not login.*

Comment: `As user 'dbo' which is the database principal for login 'sa' ` Can you back up that assertion?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up Logins with Users. Logins are server-wide principals whereas Users are database-specific principals.